# How to alert user if the name already present in the database when user try to add. Using Django, Ajax

Tags: jquery, django

This is code for adding the Name and Id for the plans. i want this code to be modified so user will get the warning msg with jquery popup if the database already have component name user entered if not then user data should be saved

HTML

```
<label>Component</label>
<input type="text" id="component_name" id="component_name" class="input_text" required><br>
<input type="text" name="plan_id" id="plan_id" class="input_text" required><br>
```

ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/insertPlans/",
        async: false,
        cache : false,
        data: {
        'component_name': component_name,
        'plan_id' : plan_id,     
},
```

url

```
    url(r'^insertPlans/','homepage.views.insertPlan'),
```

view.py

```
def insertPlan(request):
    try:
        logger.info("{insertplan} --called")
        plan_id = request.POST['plan_id']
        component_name = request.POST['component_name']
        query = "insert into dbo.mydbname(name, plans) \
                        values('%s', '%s')" % (component_name,
                        plan_id)
        DBOperations.insertToDB(query,"nameproj")
        context = fieldView.addCustomerView(request)
    except:
        logger.error(str(traceback.format_exc()))
    request.session['last_activity'] = str(datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
    return render_to_response('homepage/addhomepage.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you definitely should not have that try/except. You're just catching errors to log them, but Django will do that for you already.

Comment: Also, why aren't you using Django models here?

Comment: I don't know much about the django, but i have to do this